# Why isn't the direct product of a group with $\Bbb Z_2$ a Schur double cover?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, homology-cohomology

Why doesn't every group $G$ have a double cover? Take $H = G \times\Bbb Z_2$, ie the direct product of G with a cycle group of order 2. Then $\Bbb Z_2$ is a central subgroup of $H$, such that $H/\Bbb Z_2 = G$. Job done.

For context, I'm teaching myself about the finite simple groups, and often in the literature it will come up about their covering groups. Eg the alternating groups have (two non-isomorphic) double covers, and $A_6$ and $A_7$ have triple covers too. I am trying to get a handle on these as a concept.

Much of the motivation for covering groups seems to come from homology, or the notion of spin in quantum mechanics - alas I don't know much about these just yet. A motivation I found that I did understand is that if you want to build a projective representation $ G\rightarrow \mathrm{PGL}(V)$, then a good way to do it is to find a covering group $H$ with central subgroup $A$ with $G=H/A$, and build a representation $H\rightarrow GL(V)$. Quotienting out by $A$ gives you the 'obvious' way to make the representation projective.

Now I'm sure building double covers just by taking direct products is cheating, but I can't put my finger on why. I think  it has something about $H$ needing to be perfect, and if you bolt on an abelian Group in a direct product, it's not perfect.

But the sources I find online seem to be split on whether $G$ or $H$ need to be perfect. Here are examples.

- Robert Wilson's *The Finite Simple Groups* only defines a covering group for a group $G$ if $G$ is perfect, and mandates that the cover $H$ be perfect too.
- On the other hand J. Weigold's *The Schur Multiplier: An Elementary Approach*, states "Schur proved the following. If $G$ is any finite group, there exists a group $H$ and a central subgroup $A$ such that $H/A = G$, and every irreducible projective representation of $G$ comes from an ordinary representation of $H$ just described". So, no mention of $G$ or $H$ being perfect.

[Apologies I don't have open source links I can share for these sources].

Please would someone help me navigate this?

Comment: The direct product is a double cover, and is the zero element of the corresponding extension group. So if the only central extension is the direct product, that's when we say that 'there isn't one', even though you are right, there is always *an* extension. Correspondingly, we generally reserve the term double cover for non-zero elements of the extension group.

Comment: In the definition of Schur Multiplier, the required condition is $A \le [H,H]$. You don't need $G$ or $H$ to be perfect, but if $G$ is perfect then so is $H$, and the Schur cover is unique up to isomorphism. If $G$ is not perfect then there can be more than one. For example $Q_8$ and $D_8$ are both Schur covers of $C_2 \times C_2$. The Schur Multiplier $A$ is always uniquely determined by $G$.

Comment: Thanks David and Derek for commenting on my question. These are both really helpful responses, and I'm going to go through them carefully, hopefully on my sunday afternoon.